Removing glossy white cover effect on mesh
I have loaded a PLY file and applied an orthophoto on top of it using BlenderGIS but the result is having a white glossy shade cover at some angles, even so there is no light in the Blender project, only the mesh with the image as its texture:

This is what the Material looks like by default, I didn't change anything:

How could I remove that white glossy shade?
I already tried to move almost all cursors in the Material tab, especially the one named "Metallic", "Roughness", "IOR" or "Specular>IOR Level" but this doesn't change anything.
Ubuntu: 22.04
Blender: 4.2.2
BlenderGIS: 2.2.10
Human Blender level: 0 (novice)

Set IOR to 1...

As as said, it has strictly no effect. Whatever value I set...

Are you sure this isn't a MatCap over your object with the Color mode just set to texture? Or are you sure you're in Rendered view?

Under Specular, put the IOR level at 0, or use an Emission shader instead of the Principled BSDF (or directly plug the Image Texture into the Output, which is like using an Emission shader)

Okay, I figured out what was going on. Thanks for your comments.
It was indeed in the "Viewport shading" menu on the top-right corner of the viewport where the mode was set to "Solid":

by changing it to "Material Preview" things look much more natural, as the original image:

and if I set the mode to "Rendered", then the adjustments on the right side are taking effect:

